# Urldecode doesn't decode innertext inside HTML

Tags: html, utf-8, utf8-decode, innertext

I have a certain encoded information:

```
%3Ctable%20align%3D%22left%22%20cellpadding%3D%220%22%20cellspacing%3D%220%22%3E%3Ctbody%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20valign%3D%22top%22%20width%3D%2216%22%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22query-color%22%20style%3D%22background-color%3A%238c2b2b%22%3E%26nbsp%3B%3C/div%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20class%3D%22label%22%20valign%3D%22top%22%3E%u05DB%u05E4%u05E8%20%u05E1%u05D1%u05D0%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20valign%3D%22top%22%20width%3D%2216%22%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22query-color%22%20style%3D%22background-color%3A%23468c2b%22%3E%26nbsp%3B%3C/div%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20class%3D%22label%22%20valign%3D%22top%22%3E%u05E0%u05EA%u05E0%u05D9%u05D4%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20valign%3D%22top%22%20width%3D%2216%22%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22query-color%22%20style%3D%22background-color%3A%232b5d8c%22%3E%26nbsp%3B%3C/div%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20class%3D%22label%22%20valign%3D%22top%22%3E%u05E4%u05EA%u05D7%20%u05EA%u05E7%u05D5%u05D5%u05D4%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20valign%3D%22top%22%20width%3D%2216%22%3E%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22query-color%22%20style%3D%22background-color%3A%23cd5200%22%3E%26nbsp%3B%3C/div%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20class%3D%22label%22%20valign%3D%22top%22%3E%u05E8%u05D0%u05E9%u05D5%u05DF%20%u05DC%u05E6%u05D9%u05D5%u05DF%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20valign%3D%22top
```

...
...

i use this line to decode it:

```
urldecode(string);
```

and i get the html decoded fine, but the text inside the labels is still the same:

```
<table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td valign="top" width="16"><div class="query-color" style="background-color:#8c2b2b">&nbsp;</div></td><td class="label" valign="top">%u05DB%u05E4%u05E8 %u05E1%u05D1%u05D0</td><td valign="top" width="16"><div class="query-color" style="background-color:#468c2b">&nbsp;</div></td><td class="label" valign="top">%u05E0%u05EA%u05E0%u05D9%u05D4</td><td valign="top" width="16"><div class="query-color" style="background-color:#2b5d8c">&nbsp;</div></td><td class="label" valign="top">%u05E4%u05EA%u05D7 %u05EA%u05E7%u05D5%u05D5%u05D4</td><td valign="top" width="16"><div class="query-color" style="background-color:#cd5200">&nbsp;</div></td><td class="label" valign="top">%u05E8%u05D0%u05E9%u05D5%u05DF %u05DC%u05E6%u05D9%u05D5%u05DF</td><td valign="top" width="16"><div class="query-color" style="background-color:#e6bf00">&nbsp;</div></td><td class="label" valign="top">%u05E8%u05DE%u05EA %u05D2%u05DF</td><td valign="top" width="16"><div class="query-color" style="background-color:#7f3acd">&nbsp;</div></td><td class="label" valign="top">%u05E8%u05DE%u05EA
```

I also tried

```
utf8_decode(urldecode(string));
```

because the text is `utf-8` (i think)

but it didn't change a thing.
is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Yes, how should php decide if the content is encoded or meant to be what it is? This is not decidable in an automated fashion. So do it manually: take the content token and decode them one by one.

Comment: The text inside the labels is not url-encoded (having a `%` in front does not make you url-encoded), so `urldecode` does not touch it. That's not surprising. Your data was not encoded in one go with `urlencode`, so it cannot be decoded in one go with `urldecode`. How to decode it? Well, how did you encode it?

Comment: i'll get deeper into the code thanks :)